# Button that Work Conditionally

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
    var p;

    for (p = 0; p < coll.length; p++) {
    coll[p].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
    });
    }
```

```html
    <button class="secondaryButton" id="Btn1"
    onclick="Funtion();document.getElementById('humble').click()" /><a href="#humble">1. The Humble Beginning (1908-1944)</a>
    <button class="collapsible" id="humble">The Humble Beginning (1908-1944)
    </button>
    <div class="content" id="humble2">
    <div>content</div>
```

I use the code above to create a button that trigger the collapsible content to open. How can I make the button only work when the content is collapsed but not when it is open?

Comment: don't use `.click()` to trigger the collapse. Toggle a CSS class instead. Use the `disabled` attribute on the button to enable/disable it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest concept is, once your button is clicked, always check to see if the target is already open, if so, then return. Since there's error-prone and incomplete code above, below is an attempt to straighten things out.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function toggleContent(o) {
                var contents = document.querySelectorAll(".collapsible .content");
                for (var i=0; i<contents.length; i++) {
                    contents[i].style.display = 'none';
                }
                document.getElementById(o.dataset.target).style.display = 'block';
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="collapsible">
            <button data-target="humble1" onclick="toggleContent(this)">1. The Humble Beginning (1908-1944)</button>
            <button data-target="humble2" onclick="toggleContent(this)">2. The Humble Middle (1908-1944)</button>
            <button data-target="humble3" onclick="toggleContent(this)">3. The Humble Ending (1908-1944)</button>
            <div class="content" id="humble1">content 1</div>
            <div class="content" id="humble2" style="display:none">content 2</div>
            <div class="content" id="humble3" style="display:none">content 3</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Basically, when each button is clicked, all content blocks are hidden, with the target remaining open.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the question is. But I think this is what you want.

```js
function a() {
var div = document.getElementById("div");
var button = document.getElementById("button");
if (div.style.visibility == "visible") {
div.style.visibility = "hidden";
button.innerHTML ="Open";
}
else  {
div.style.visibility = "visible";
button.innerHTML ="Close";
}
}
```

```html
<div id="div" style="visibility: hidden;">
Some content
</div>
<button onclick="a();" id="button">Open</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach is closer to your existing code. Perhaps it gives you some more insight in what actually happens in your code.

it's all up to you :)

**1st**:
Your humble2 div is broken in the HTML because it does not have a closing tag.
Fix this first.

**2nd**:
The best practise is not to change the content height through JS but use classes that represent the collapsed or expanded status.

```
.collapsed {
    height:0;
}
```

Now you can ask for the status of the content div.

```
if (content.classList.contains('collapsed') == 1){
  content.classList.add('collapsed');
} else {
  content.classList.remove('collapsed');
}
```

**note 1**:
I'd go for `height` instead of `maxHeight` to prevent other strange behavior later.
Only use `maxHeight` if you have a good reason.

**note 2**:
give your content div an ID for easier selection instead of using `this.nextElementSilbling`.
At the moment you can never change something on your HTML DOM without making your code fail because the next silbling has changed.

**note 3**:
If you want to stay with the height concept:
Your `if (content.style.maxHeight) {}` will allways return `true` because it returns a string that is never empty.
Even if the `maxHeight` is 0 pixels it will return `'0px'` which is not an empty string and tho `true`.

But you already figured out that this is not working as intended. So you set the `maxHeight` to `null` which results in `false`.

better do this:
`(content.style.maxHeight == '0px') {...}`
and:
`content.style.maxHeight = '0px';`

This way you allways use the string type and prevent unintended behavior.

here you canf ind more about the Truthly and falsy concept in javascript:
[Truthy and falsy in JavaScript](http://11heavens.com/falsy-and-truthy-in-javascript)